# Laravel strange array/object storing issue

Tags: php, laravel

I'm retrieving list of id's from the table:

```
$users = User::all();
$ids_list = $users->lists('id')->all();
```

Then I'm doing some manipulations, removing certain ids from the list:

```
unset($ids_list[$i]);
```

Then I'm trying to store it in the database, but receive strange results:
Sometimes it stores like this: `[3,13]`, and sometimes like this:`{"0":2,"2":27}`

Whys is it acting this way?

Comment: It's not very clear how you are applying the unset. The query you have done it's an array of OBJECTS. This means that $ids_list[$i]->id will return your requested field. You can convert queries to arrays like this: $ids_list = $users->lists('id')->all()->toArray();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that Laravel is json-encoding the values you are passing. When you json encode an array, if the keys are not incrementing numerical values starting with 0, then the json-encoding treats it like an object with numeric property names.

Since you are removing values, the incrementing chain is broken in the middle somewhere.

Try running your final array through `array_values()` before trying to save. Array values will re-index your array so there are no gaps in the numbering.

Here's the documentation for array_values: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

---

**Edit 1 (extra explanation)**

```
//Define our array
$arr = ['why', 'hello', 'there'];

//Array looks like this:
//Array (
//    [0] => 'why',
//    [1] => 'hello',
//    [2] => 'there'
//)

json_encode($arr); //Results in: ["why","hello","there"]

//Break the auto-incrementing numerical keys by removing a middle value
unset($arr[1]);

//Array now looks like this:
//Array (
//    [0] => 'why',
//    [2] => 'there'
//)

json_encode($arr); //Results in {"0":"why","2":"there"}

//The json is now an object because an array in javascript can't have a break
//in the numerical chain of its keys. Only an object can represent in javascript
//what our array looks like now

//In order to return the array to an unbroken chain of auto-incrementing
//numerical keys, we ask PHP just to give us the values of the array
$arr = array_values($arr);

//Array now looks like this:
//Array (
//    [0] => 'why',
//    [1] => 'there'
//)

json_encode($arr); //Results in ["why","there"]
```

Comment: I'm adding a little more detail to help illustrate what PHP is doing internally, for your and others' reference. Hopefully it'll be helpful. That'll help kill the 7 minutes =P